# Is the google docs api incompatible with C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, google-docs, google-docs-api

I've added references to all the required docs api dll's, but I still get missing reference exceptions when I try to compile.

Comment: Missing references to *what*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the project's "Target Framework" from the VS2010 default, which is ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile", to ".Net Framework 4" and everything works fine now.

Comment: this could be the answer to perhaps a thousand of C# app problems, Wy do they placed the Client Profile as default I wonder...?

Comment: @DavidConde gotta agree...I've hit this so many times. ;( It doesn't take long to figure it out any more. ;)

Comment: @kenny, true that... I tend to find that error quicker than most of the others... however, **very** annoying to add a reference and find out that you are on client profile...